# Deploying docker container to ecs fargate - command is not found when launching working docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm working on deploying some of our containers from an existing docker swarm into an aws ecs cluster. The container images are identical between swarm and ecs version that I'm deploying.

Most of the containers deployed without issue. One container in particular though refuses to start and gives the error

```
/bin/sh: 1: /srv/src/enketo_express/setup/docker/start.sh: not found
```

Running this container in docker swarm, and locally works fine. That .sh file does exist and starts the process.

https://github.com/enketo/enketo-express/blob/master/Dockerfile

Here's my ecs container definition - omitted some parts for brevity:

```json
{
    "family": "wsb-dfp-enketo",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "enketo",
            "image": "enketo/enketo-express:6.0.0",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "enketo-8005-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8005,
                    "hostPort": 8005,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "command": [
                "/bin/bash",
                "/srv/src/enketo_express/setup/docker/start.sh"
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "DEBUG",
                    "value": "openrosa*"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "config",
                    "containerPath": "/srv/src/enketo_express/",
                    "readOnly": false
                }
            ],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "workingDirectory": "/srv/src/enketo_express",
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/wsb-dfp-enketo",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::...:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "config",
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
                "fileSystemId": "fs-...",
                "rootDirectory": "/volumes/enketo/config"
            }
        }
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "256",
    "memory": "512",
    "ephemeralStorage": {
        "sizeInGiB": 21
    },
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}
```

Has anyone seen similar issues, and found a resolution?

Comment: It's weird you are specifying `/bin/bash` in the command, but the error says `/bin/sh`. That's the only thing that stands out to me. Maybe remove the `command` and `entrypoint` settings from your task definition, since the `COMMAND` is already specified in the Dockerfile, you shouldn't need to specify those.

Comment: I have tried it both ways to be honest, I have left it empty and gotten the error with sh and a similar error with bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overrwriting the entire `/srv/src/enketo_express` folder and all folders underneath it with an EFS volume mounted to `/srv/src/enketo_express`. Since that is where your docker image's application files are, you are basically making those application files invisible to the operating system running in the docker container, and replacing them with whatever is in the `/volumes/enketo/config` folder in your EFS volume.

The problem configuration is here:

```
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "config",
                    "containerPath": "/srv/src/enketo_express/",
                    "readOnly": false
                }
            ],
```

I assume that `containerPath` setting probably needs to be something like `"/srv/src/enketo_express/config/"`

Comment: Wow, that seems like it would do it! and now I feel very dumb for how obvious that is. I'm testing now. Thank you for looking!

Comment: That resolved that problem! onto the next one :) Thanks again Mark.